# XSLT compound condition that uses ends-with

Tags: xslt

and I have some code now that says:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$Admin = 2">
        <img src="../Lists/Announcement/Attachments/1/Banner.jpg" style="height:189px; width:568px;" title="{@Title};" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <img src="../Lists/Announcement/Attachments/{@ID}/Banner.jpg" style="height:189px; width:568px;" title="{@Title};" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I would like to compound the condition so that it will also accept an attachment called banner.png also, and show banner.png. 
If I use the substring function and give it a negative number will it count backwards from the end of the string?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide some examples of input and the corresponding output expected for each case.

Answer (score 1):

> If I use the substring function and give it a negative number will it count backwards from the end of the string?

No. (What made you think it would? Did you actually look for a specification? Did you try it? Guessing, and asking on SO whether your guess is correct, doesn't sound like a very efficient way of getting things done.)